# How to setup webdriverio related tests to be build in travis-ci

Tags: selenium, travis-ci, webdriver-io

This is my test project [Github Repo for React test](https://github.com/sabbiu/react-test)

*Got it working!!*

It builds successfully on my pc in chrome and firefox

But, when I try to build it in travis CI, it doesn't execute. By the way, I am trying the test to be run headless mode as in [travis-ci docs headless chrome](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-the-Chrome-addon-in-the-headless-mode)

What am I missing?

This is my `.travis.yml` file content:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - '8.9'

dist: trusty

addons:
  chrome: stable

before_install:
  - # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
```

Travis CI Error Log:

```
react-test@1.0.0 test /home/travis/build/sabbiu/react-test
> wdio wdio.conf.js
[13:34:05]  COMMAND POST     "/wd/hub/session"
[13:34:05]  DATA        {"desiredCapabilities": {"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.12.0","name":"webdriverio"}}}
ERROR: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 
(9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 4.14.12-041412-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.35 seconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'travis-job-sabbiu-react-test-360271390', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.12-041412-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
chrome
at new RuntimeError (/home/travis/build/sabbiu/react-test/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
at Request._callback (/home/travis/build/sabbiu/react-test/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:316:39)
at Request.self.callback (/home/travis/build/sabbiu/react-test/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/sabbiu/react-test/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/sabbiu/react-test/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
The command "npm test" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "mocha": "^5.0.5",
    "selenium-standalone": "^6.13.0",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.13",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.10",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "^0.1.4",
    "webdriverio": "^4.12.0"
  }
}
```

**UPDATES**

I got it working with xvfb. But, I am still looking for it to work with chrome --headless.

`.travis.yml` file with xvfb

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - '8.9'

sudo: required

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

addons:
  chrome: stable

before_install:
  # starting a GUI to run tests, per https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-a-GUI
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - "npm config set spin false"

before_script:
  - "npm install"

script: "npm test"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was missing `chromeOptions` in `wdio.config.js` file

```
capabilities: [{
    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 5,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome',

    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['headless', 'disable-gpu']
    }
}],
```

After puting that it worked like a charm.

Comment: For anyone passing through, note that this is for WebDriver.io v4. In WebDrive.io v5 you'll need to do `'goog:chromeOptions': { args: ['headless', 'disable-gpu'] }` instead.